# How can I upgrade Numpy in just one version of Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, opencv, pip

I am trying to get OpenCV working, but the issue with this is that my Python27 Numpp version is too old. Every time I write "install --upgrade numpy", I am told that Numpy is already up to date in C:Python37. How can I update Numpy in C:Python27 rather than 37? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The version of `pip` is tied to a specific Python installation. So `pip` on my computer works for Python 3.7, while `pip2` is for Python 2.7. Are you sure you're using the correct version of `pip`.

Comment: @bnaecker I am using pip3, I think this is the issue. My computer doesn't seem to recognize 'pip2'. How can I run install numpy using pip2?

Comment: It may just be called `pip` on your machine. If you do `pip --version`, that will tell you exactly which version. It may also be called `pip2.7` or something more specific.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll try that

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me as I am on a mac, but I think a similar command should work on windows:

```
<path/to/particular/version/of/python> -m pip install numpy==<version number>
```

As an example from my machine:

```sh
$ # numpy versions before changes
$ python3.6 -m pip list | grep numpy
numpy                  1.14.5
$ python3.7 -m pip list | grep numpy
numpy                    1.15.2

$ # updating numpy for python3.6
$ python3.6 -m pip install numpy==1.16.1
.
.
.

$ # numpy versions after changes
$ python3.6 -m pip list | grep numpy
numpy                  1.16.1
$ python3.7 -m pip list | grep numpy
numpy                    1.15.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running `pip install --upgrade numpy`

Try `where pip` and `where python` to get an idea of which version of python your are executing pip from.  Use `which pip` instead on Mac or Linux.

I assume it will return `c:\python27\Scripts\pip.exe` if so then try...

```
c:\python27\Scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the first answer by JCutrer, after installing numpy on the specified version, you need to run the python.exe interpreter of the specified version.

So, assuming  you did
`c:\python27\Scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade numpy`, the libraries have been installed for python27, now you can run python from the below path, or set this path as interpreter in your IDE.

`c:\python27\bin\python27.exe` (or python.exe)

Comment: If you only want to use python27, you can also set it default globally by editing Environment Variables.